# Delphi 6 alongside RAD Studio 2009

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, delphi-6

I need to migrate to RAD Studio and have this installed on a new workstation. At the moment I still need to develop with Delphi 6 until we get all the necessary control updates and sort out the version control.

So my question is can I just install Delphi 6 on the same machine with no adverse impact for either product?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no problem to install D6 and RAD 2009 at the same machine.
I think that it's better install first the previos version (first D6 and after D2009), but it's not absolutly necesary.

Regards and excuse for my bad english.

Comment: Thanks for that I will give it a go and report back. I already have RAD 2009 on the machine so will try with DELPHI 6 second.

Comment: In case of problems, uninstall D2009 first! Then install D6, then re-install S2009 again. Chances are that the installation of D6 will mess up your D2009 registry settings. (And undo certain file associations.)

Comment: From my experience it IS necessary to install former version first, then the latter.

Comment: It installed fine with Delphi 6 after RAD Studio 2009 (it was already on the machine so thought I would try). Now I can start the slow process of miogration, thanks.

Comment: Sorry spell checker ignore. It should of course be migration.

Answer (score 2):

Installing them on the same system is no problem at all.

For migration, our clients have good experience with migrating to Delphi 2007 first, then do the Unicode migration to Delphi 2009 or Delphi 2010 second.

Doing both migration at the same time can work, but usually result in a migration that is too complex to do in one step.

--jeroen

Answer (score 0):

I have delphi 3 to 2009 installed in my machine and I dont have any problem with any of the the Delphi IDEs. Only the BDS 2006's C++ IDE does not work anymore. There is a problem when C++ builder 2006 and 2007 installed in the same machine.

Comment: Wow. I thought I was pushing it but you have all of them from 3.